# unable to receive data into the buffer stm32l0 using HAL_UART_Receive

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I have an custom designed board with STM32L071 and EnOcean TCM515. Using USART1 I'm able to transmit the packet(ESP3 protocol) to get version number of the TCM515 module. `HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)enocean_ver, sizeof(enocean_ver), HAL_MAX_DELAY);`
using logic analyzer I can see the transmit and response packet from the TCM515 module, also probed the pins of the communication channel I can see the packets transmitted and received. 
But using `HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)buf,  sizeof(buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);` data is not stored into the buffer, I believe its a software issue, am I missing something?

```
uint8_t enocean_ver[]={0x55, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x70, 0x03, 0x09};

 UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

  int main(void) {

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  HAL_UART_GetState(&huart1);
  char buf[40];
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)enocean_ver, sizeof(enocean_ver), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)buf,  sizeof(buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
 while(1);
}

static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
 {

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 57600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);

 }

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
 {
         __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
         __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
         if(huart->Instance==USART1){
     /*USART1 GPIO Configuration
     PB6     ------> USART1_TX
     PB7     ------> USART1_RX*/

     GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
     GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
     GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
     GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
     GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_USART1;
     HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
         }

 void MX_GPIO_Init() {
 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

     /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */

     __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
}
```

Comment: Does HAL_UART_Receive indicate a timeout or is the received data not as expected? Try to single step through that function to see if it receives anything. Maybe the answer arrives before you call the receive function.

Comment: yes it is going into UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout() function, and the data buffer 'buf' has no data.